# how do i achieve following condition in codeigniter sql?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a table with the name message_system.

and structure of the table is as follow:

```
    message_system => message_id(primary key)->sender_id->receiver_id->
               message->time(current time stamp)
```

lets consider a `$user_id = 1` and I want to select the row from the table
something like

```
select * from message_system where sender_id = $user_id or receiver_id = $user_id
```

and from the yielded result I want select only single result which has recently stored according to time stamp.

actually I want to select recent message from the message thread between two user..

**edit 1:**

*I want to get recent message from the table  with respect to each 
 unique pair of   (user1_id and user2_id). Either it is(user1_id,
 user2_id) or  (user2_id, user1_id)   usually user id of logged in user
 would be on of the id and another is  id of  user who have been
 messaged to current logged in user.*

**edit 2:**

example:

lets consider user1 is logged in and he has messaged to user2. and later messaged to user3 and user4.
and those all messages are stored in the table and now i want to query such that it retrieves only recent message with user2,user3,user4 in user1 wall. not all their history

**edit 3 :**

query should return recent message of logged in user  with user1 and recent message of logged in user  user2 and user3 so on.

thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi @vasanth can you given an example for the edit section in your question

Comment: hi @ saurabh2836 kindly see the updated question

Comment: when will you send message to user2,user3 and user4 after user1 logs out and does your database manage and change some status for the send message by logged in user

Comment: @saurabh2836 I didn't get you

Comment: when will you send the message and show structure of your message table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With little bit modification of the table I have come up with an idea.

earlier my table structure was:

```
message_system => message_id(primary key)->sender_id->receiver_id->
               message->time(current time stamp)
```

after modification:

```
message_system => message_id(primary key)->sender_id->receiver_id->
               message->time(current time stamp)->unique_pair_key
```

**unique_pair_key** is to identify the message between two user uniquely and value would be something like this `($sender_id^2 + $receiver_id^2)` 
which is unique for given pair.

all messages between two particular user would be identify by this unique_pair_key.

so taking logged_in user as the reference, with respect to him only recent message with different user (if there any)  should be shown (similar to stack overflow recent inbox message )and on clicking that particular message it should direct to their message thread.

model/model.php

```
     public function get_notification($user_id)
          {

       $this->db->where("receiver_id",$user_id);
       $this->db->where("sender_id",$user_id); 

    //because recent message would either be sent or received by logged in user

    $this->db->select_max('message_id');

   // latest message would have greatest value of id

    $this->db->group_by('unique_pair_key');
    $query = $this->db->get('message_system ');

   //returns latest message_id with unique pair in which on of  them is $userid.
}
```

above query only generates message id  with that we can further query to get message

If you have any better solution please share with us.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from message_system where sender_id = $user_id or receiver_id = $user_id
```

would translate in CodeIgniter in:

```
$this->db->where('sender_id', $user_id);
$this->db->or_where('receiver_id', $user_id);
$query = $this->db->get('message_system');
$row = $query->row();
```

If you want the most recent input, you could order by `time`, and if you know you only need one row, limit to 1:

```
$this->db->where('sender_id', $user_id);
$this->db->or_where('receiver_id', $user_id);
$this->db->order_by('time', 'desc');//order by time
$this->db->limit('1');//limit the query to only one row
$query = $this->db->get('message_system');
$row = $query->row();// get only first
```

**UPDATE:** 
The solution above works if you want to find one entry corresponding to one given user.
If you want to find last entry for a given pair of users, thing would look like this if unknown who would be the sender and who would be te receiver:

```
$this->db->where_in('sender_id', array($user_id1, $user_id2));
$this->db->where_in('receiver_id', array($user_id1, $user_id2));
$this->db->order_by('time', 'desc');//order by time
$this->db->limit('1');//limit the query to only one row
$query = $this->db->get('message_system');
$row = $query->row();// get only first
```

And like this if you know exactly who is who:

```
$this->db->where('sender_id', $user_id1);
$this->db->where('receiver_id', $user_id2);
$this->db->order_by('time', 'desc');//order by time
$this->db->limit('1');//limit the query to only one row
$query = $this->db->get('message_system');
$row = $query->row();// get only first
```

Comment: hey thank you for your answer. kindly see my edited question. your answer met only my half requirements.

Comment: thank you very much.i will check that and let you know.

Comment: hey in my case i know only id of logged in user and i want to retrieve only recent messages with all other user with respect to logged in user.    i think above solution wont satisfy the condition.for example query should return recent message of logged in user and with  user1 and recent message of logged in user and user2 and user3 so on..

Comment: I did answer the original question and more. If you continually update your question, we may never get to the bottom of of this. It would be correct to accept the answer and post a new question. And please think of an enunciation that would cover all the aspects of your problem.

Comment: i would accept your answer as I fail to convey the problem properly. but I  kept edit  the question only to make the question more clearer.

Comment: Should the logged_in user be considered only as sender or as receiver too?

Comment: yes. something like facebook notification center where you will find recent message of your friend (if he have sent any message to you) and on clicking that you would be redirect to that particular thread.\